How do can I GET AN ARRAY OF ALL WEEKDAYS in javascript
My application includes Java 21 on the server side and React.js on the client side. According to the Locale, I must get a list/array of weekdays. I have no limits on dependencies to use, as long as they are free/open-source.
I can do that in Java using the following code (didn't invest too much time writing it) and calling an API from the client to get it, but I want something that is JavaScript and if I can save the API request:
String[] weekDays = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getWeekdays();
System.out.print("weekDays:\n\t");
Arrays.stream(weekDays).forEach(x -> System.out.print(x + ", "));
System.out.println();

**Output:**
daysOfWeek:
    , Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, 

The code in Java for weekdays in German:
    String[] daysOfWeekGER = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN).getWeekdays();
    System.out.print("daysOfWeekGER:\n\t");
    Arrays.stream(daysOfWeekGER).forEach(x -> System.out.print(x + ", "));
    System.out.println();
    
    **Output**
    daysOfWeekGER:
        , Sonntag, Montag, Dienstag, Mittwoch, Donnerstag, Freitag, Samstag, 

I am looking for something similar in JavaScript.
This question is NOT a duplicate for Getting localized day of week as my question is about getting a list of all weekdays depending on the Locale vs that question.
I searched for similar questions before creating this one, as I need and want a solution. I read my question carefully before flagging it as a duplicate, as I couldn't find any on StackOverflow.
My Requirements For The Solution:

Generate an array of weekdays depending on Locale.
The Locale affects the names of the weekdays.
The Locale affects the list of weekdays, whether the first weekday is Saturday, Sunday, or Monday.
No data should be hard-coded (it will affect development, tests, and maintenance).

Java code for similar requirements
This example includes the code above.
Yes, I know that new Locale(stringLanguage, stringCountry) is deprecated from Java 19, and in Java 22+ I need to use Locale.of(stringLanguage, stringCountry).
The result MUST be AN ARRAY OF STRINGS containing the weekdays' full names, a SINGLE STRING is not a valid solution. I know how to get the weekday name of a specific date—that's not the question.
Creating a hardcoded array for every language is impractical and wastes time and effort.
If there's no solution, I will do it on the Java server, and the React.js client will call an API endpoint to receive it.

@MattMorgan, Apologies; I just noticed that.

In Java use the DayOfWeek enum to get the names of the days of the week in your desired language, for example Arrays.stream(DayOfWeek.values()) .map(dow -> dow.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.GERMAN)) .toList(). DateFormatSymbols is what I would have used in Java 7, so not in the last decade.

You could use Intl.DateTimeFormat:


function getLocalizedWeekdays(locale) {
  const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, { weekday: 'long' });
  return [...Array(7).keys()].map((dayIndex) => {
    // January 1st 2024 is a Sunday in UTC.
    const date = new Date(
      Date.UTC(/*year=*/2024, /*monthIndex=*/0, /*day=*/1 + dayIndex),
    );
    return formatter.format(date);
  });
}

console.log('"en-US" =', getLocalizedWeekdays('en-US'));
console.log('"de-DE" =', getLocalizedWeekdays('de-DE'));
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




Extended answer to dynamically get the first day of the week based on country, as requested by OP in the comments.
As far as I can tell, there is no robust way in the Javascript standard library to tell which day of the week is the first per country currently (there is this Intl.Locale.prototype.getWeekInfo() however, it has limited availability, notably not working in Firefox yet). So you need to define that mapping yourself or utilize a third-party library like Moment.js:


function getLocalizedWeekdays(locale) {
  const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, { weekday: 'long' });
  const firstDayOfWeek = moment.localeData(locale).firstDayOfWeek();
  return [...Array(7).keys()].map((dayIndex) => {
    // January 1st 2024 is a Sunday in UTC.
    const date = new Date(
      Date.UTC(
        /*year=*/2024,
        /*monthIndex=*/0,
        /*day=*/1 + ((firstDayOfWeek + dayIndex) % 7),
      ),
    );
    return formatter.format(date);
  });
}

console.log('"en-US" =', getLocalizedWeekdays('en-US'));
console.log('"he-UA" =', getLocalizedWeekdays('he-UA'));
console.log('"ar-FR" =', getLocalizedWeekdays('ar-FR'));
console.log('"es-IL" =', getLocalizedWeekdays('es-IL'));
console.log('"en-NZ" =', getLocalizedWeekdays('en-NZ'));
console.log('"de-DE" =', getLocalizedWeekdays('de-DE'));
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.30.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>




For Christians the first day of the week is Monday, for Muslims it's Saturday, for Jews it's Sunday. If the local is "he-ua" (Hebrew, Ukraine), "ar-FR" (Arabic, France), or "es-IL" (Spanish, Israel) - which day is the first day of the week for each of them? Does it go by country or language of the Locale? I don't want to have 3 (or more) arrays.

If I need to create an map with country-code and the first name of the week then that's missing the purpose: (1) That map will have about 200 elements (key-value); (2) I don't wnat to waste time on creating this hard-coded map; (3) When a country change it's name or there's a new country (e.g., South Sudan, etc.) I will need to change my code.
The code in Java will work everytime, all the time.

It seems moment.js has a function firstDayOfWeek()

check Intl.Locale.prototype.getWeekInfo(), should be enough for you to do this in one line of code

Thanks, Mike and @LãNgọcHải integrated your suggestions into answer :)

@BinyaminRegev did you see I changed my answer to not hardcoding a map? Also, FYI, all the biggest companies, e.g., OpenAI, Meta, Google, Amazon, etc., have a bunch of not best practices and duplication everywhere. Sometimes duck-taping something together and getting it out the door is best and is expected :)

@SashSinha - I like your answer and it gave me another direction to check to reach a solution. But, as I wrote in a previous comment, creating/hard-coding mapping a country to the first weekday is not an option, there are about 200 countries in the world, and creating this map will take a lot of time (unjustified) and will need to be maintained (again, unjustified). The direction My question is not academic, or for training - I am looking at all the development principles and best practices.

I think you are not understanding... There is no creating/hard-coding mapping a country to the first weekday anymore? The answer uses Moment.js to get the first weekday: https://i.sstatic.net/2IZplUM6.png

@BinyaminRegev, FWIW, Christians in the US typically consider Sunday the first day of the week.

I know, I worked in several countries around the world and many cultures, regulations, and languages. From NZ to America, only in Antarctica, I haven't worked yet (too cold)

You should keep in mind: "Moment.js is a legacy project, now in maintenance mode. In most cases, you should choose a different library."

Sorry, @SashSinha, I just saw your reference to Moment.js library - I will check if it's something I can use and have a solution.

Why does the "de-DE" output in the second snippet start at Tuesday? Also "en-NZ" does it.

@SashSinha, using the Moment.js library does the trick - thank you for the solution.

Europe, so a positive offset.
